# Pick a column from a table depending on a where clause and then match that to another column in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable named `$generic` which is passed into the function which loads the `SQL` query, this is used to form a match with the `slug` column in the table `cms_web_pages`; so in this instance lets say `$generic` equals 'bar' the query then grabs the `id` of the matched row and uses the `id` to match rows inside a second table `cms_web_page_content` with the column `page_id` then grab all the data from the table `cms_web_page_content` to be placed inside an array.

Table "cms_web_pages":

```
id | title | slug
-----------------
1  | foo   | bar
2  | bar   | foo
```

Table "cms_web_page_content":

```
id | title | content | position | page_id
-----------------------------------------
1  | foo   | bar     | 1        | 1
2  | bar   | foo     | 2        | 1
3  | doh   | doh     | 1        | 2
```

SQL query:

```
$link = db_connect();

$qry = mysqli_query($link,
                    "SELECT page.*, content.*
                     FROM cms_web_pages AS page
                     WHERE page.slug = '".$generic."'

                     LEFT JOIN cms_web_page_content AS content
                     ON page.id = content.page_id)

                     ORDER BY content.position ASC")

                     or die(mysqli_error($link)
                    );

$content = array();
```

Thank you in advance anyone who can help.

Comment: JFYI, your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use as :
"SELECT page.*, content.*
                     FROM cms_web_pages AS page
                     LEFT JOIN cms_web_page_content AS content
                     ON (page.id = content.page_id)

                     WHERE page.slug = '".$generic."'

                     ORDER BY content.position ASC"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, after trying your solution it did not pull any rows back im afraid. `if(mysqli_num_rows($qry) !== 1): echo "No rows where found"; endif;` executed when the page was loaded.

Comment: Apologies I just realised that `if(mysqli_num_rows($qry) !== 1):` would always be true unless only 1 row returned so i changed it to `if(mysqli_num_rows($qry) < 1):` and it now works, tyvm.